# Relationship between function decidability and set decidability

Tags: logic, set-theory, formal-languages, decidability

Let $\Sigma$ denote an arbitrary
language. If $\omega = \mathbb{N} + \{ 0\}$, a $\Sigma$-mixed function is a
function s.t. $\mathcal{D}_f \subseteq \omega^n \times \Sigma^{*m}$, with $n, m,
\geq 0$, and $Im_f = \omega \lor Im_f = \Sigma$ holds. We say a $\Sigma$-mixed
function is $\Sigma$-effectively computable if there is some algorithmic procedure (AP) $\mathbb{P}$ s.t.

- Given an input in $\omega^n \times \Sigma^{*m} \in \mathcal{D}_f$, $\mathbb{P}$ outputs the
  value of $f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\alpha})$.
- Given an input in $\omega^n \times \Sigma^{*m} \not\in \mathcal{D}_f$, $\mathbb{P}$ does not halt.

The notion of AP here given is non-rigorous but can be accepted for our purposes.

We say a set $S \subseteq \omega^n \times \Sigma^{*m}$ is effectively computable (or decidable) if its characteristic function is effectively computable.

From the definitions above, it should follow that if $f$ is $\Sigma$-effectively computable, then $\mathcal{D}_f$ is $\Sigma$-computable. Otherwise, the distinction between the two points in the definition of a $\Sigma$-effectively computable function would make no sense. In other words, it seems to be a theorem that

> The domain of any $\Sigma$-effectively computable function is a decidable set.

This property is not stated in any section of my textbook. It seems, although perhaps rather simple, to be important. I wonder if there's some defect in my logic, since I would not expect my textbook to omit such a property.

Comment: I don't see why you think the distinction between the two bullet points doesn't make sense if ${\cal D}_f$ is not decidable. What is your textbook?

Comment: Because for the distinction to make sense, the AP must be able to decide whether the input is in the domain of the function or not (halt in the first case, never halt in the latter). So the domain must be decidable. Unfortunately, my textbook is not only in Spanish but a custom textbook written by the professors at my local university.

Comment: I don't think that's the intention. The AP just follows its instructions on any given input. E.g., the input could be a representation of a Turing machine and the AP could simulate execution of the Turing machine starting with a blank tape. The AP doesn't need to know in advance whether it's going to terminate. Sadly, the modern terminology is quite confusing: what is now being called effectively computable is what used to be called partial recursive. The new terminology gives the wrong impression about what an effective computation computes.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. There is no deciding involved. Your comment should be an answer by the way. Thanks!!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer (without the whinge about terminology $\ddot{\smile}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that you thought the AP would need to decide in advance whether its input was in the domain of $f$. That isn't the intention: the AP just follows its instructions on any given input. E.g., the input could be a representation of a Turing machine and the AP could simulate execution of the Turing machine starting with a blank tape. The AP doesn't need to know in advance whether it's going to terminate on any given argument.

Comment: Thanks for answering!